# how to know main.xml (main view) has been clicked in android

Tags: android

Could anyone guide how to detect whether main view (main.xml) has been clicked.
My main view is rendered this way.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bottombar" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the clickhandler,

```
RelativeLayout rlmain = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
rlmain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Log.i("I m cliked", " ");

    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should also tell, what problem are facing. what happens when you tapes on the view.

Comment: I found out other views were overlapping the view.

Answer (score 1):

```
RelativeLayout rlmain = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
        rlmain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.i("I m cliked", "Clicked ok!!!!!");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the activity which sets the main layout override the onTouchEvent as in below.

```
  @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    int action = e.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {


    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(e);

}
```